# How can we reward users who rewrite bad questions to fit quality standards?

Tags: discussion

Recently(ish) the question [Sources for Christian themes and motifs in Naruto?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24028/sources-for-christian-themes-and-motifs-in-naruto) made an appearance in meta because someone noticed the sheer amount of downvotes it had and found it to be strange, considering the legitimacy of the question. It was quickly established that the question was originally much more lacking than its current state, but probably no longer deserved the score it had.

But, as Killua noted in a comment, the question received four downvotes before it was edited, and since [SE prevents questions with a score of -4 or less from being bumped upon edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped), the question remained at low score until someone went to the trouble of making an entire meta post about it.

Of course, the topic of the question probably played a role in the initial downvote barrage, but that's a different post.

Simply put, is there any way for questions downvoted past the point of bumpability to be given a second look once whatever issue they have is solved? Do we consider this too much of a corner case to bother with?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I'd recommend that experienced users browse questions at http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest rather than just http://anime.stackexchange.com/. But a more robust solution would still be preferable.

Comment: I don't think there is designed to be a good solution for that, because it really is expected of users to do that just because. But you can always find a good answer by them and award it a bounty if you like.

Comment: One minor clarification - it's not quite that questions at -4 or less don't get bumped on edit; it's that they vanish from the front page altogether no matter what.

Comment: I agree, we should encourage people who've fixed up their questions, this has happened with a few other ones, until they've gotten edits or a good answer to justify the Q

Comment: Similar case of movies and TV discussed over meta  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262255/dont-hide-very-low-scored-questions-from-the-frontpage-if-they-have-a-bounty

Answer (score 8):

While I agree that this is an unfortunate thing that can happen, it's not a huge problem. There are currently only [13 open non-ID questions at a score of -4 or less](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-4%20-%5Bidentification-request%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ano), plus 6 more questions with the same characteristics that are deleted (I've excluded spam and nonsense from this count).

Note that if the post is closed and then somebody edits it, it gets kicked into the reopen queue, so there will automatically be additional eyes on it in that case.

One thing that users with 2k+ rep (10k+ once we graduate) can do is take a look at [/tools](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tools) occasionally. It has a bunch of useful data, one of which is a list of the lowest voted questions in the past such-and-such-number of days. Currently, it looks like this for the past thirty days:

[image: lowest-voted questions]

If you find something voted abnormally low, you can vote on it, post about it in meta or on chat, etc.